# Magento 2.2.0 - Display Recently Viewed Products block on Product Detail page

Tags: magento2, product, blocks

***Approach One***

- Login to Admin panel
- Click on Content -> Blocks
- Create new **product-detail** block and edit then toggle show/hide
  editor which will show insert widget option
- Click on insert widget select "Recently Viewed Products" from
  dropdown, add number of product to display (ex - 5)
- Select template from dropdown then click on insert widget
- Click on save Block

Although `<p>{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" uiComponent="widget_recently_viewed" page_size="5" show_attributes="name,image,price" show_buttons="add_to_cart" template="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml"}}</p>` works in **home-page** block

***Approach Two***

For testing purpose added below code in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view`

```
<block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
<action method="setPageSize">
    <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
</action>
```

Final code for `catalog_product_view`

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>

         <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
            <action method="setPageSize">
                <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

Did reindexing and cleared cache too but both the above approaches are not working.

- How could I make this work and show recently viewed products block on
  product detail page ?
- Does Magento 2 supports `local.xml` just like earlier mage versions ?

Comment: Above section is not working for you?

Comment: You can directly call recently product in template file using call block no need to do xml or other way.

Comment: What is the correct approach ? Using xml/call directly in template/create widget from admin ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working by using below code in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` for testing purpose

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
    <action method="setPageSize">
       <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
    </action>
  </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can add above snippet to `catalog_product_view.xml` file of your custom theme.

Comment: `cacheable="false"` - will disable page caching completely.

Comment: Downvotes should be explained, upvoting to counteract.

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately the [accepted answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/199915/24109) didn't work for me and I wasn't able to use [widget instance layout updates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/199892/24109) in my use case

If for whatever reason you need to add a 'Recently Viewed' products block specifically via layout xml, here's my solution (tested in version 2.2.2):

I decided to use the same class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed` which the 'Recently Viewed' Product widget uses in my block declaration.

```
<!-- Basic recently viewed products block -->
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" name="recently_viewed" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
        <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

This will render a simple grid with the last 4 products view by the user.

You can configure the block further, just as you would the widget instance:

```
<!-- Configured recently viewed products block -->
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" name="recently_viewed" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
        <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
        <!-- 'Product attributes to show' configuration -->
        <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price,learn_more</argument>
        <!-- 'Buttons to show' configuration -->
        <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

One thing to note is that the argument values for `show_attributes` and `show_buttons` need to be declared as comma delimited strings (no spaces).

Declaring them as arrays or including spaces next to your comma's won't work due to the way the UI Component parse the content before Knockout renders it.

And since I said Knockout... it should play nicely with FPC, should.

Finally this solution doesn't use the **'action'** instruction which appears to have been [deprecated](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. cacheable="false" makes the whole page uncacheable which is not advisable.

Comment: Where are the above files?

Comment: @ChrisK The code snippets need to be added to layout xml files, which one depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are unfamiliar with with layout xml check the docs [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html), there will also be other questions on here related to layout xml in m2

Answer (score 6):

**Recently Viewed Products product details page now try this.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer so far as it works natively and is compatible with FPC

Comment: Magento 2.3.2 recently viewed widgets do not work.

Comment: Hello, How to customize layout style ?

Answer (score 3):

Just keep below code in your template file for get recently viewed products in any place,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: If I am testing with luma theme, in which template file, should I place above snippet ?

Comment: You can placed any file in your system its working fine.

Comment: @Vikram Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: You can add it inside vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Comment: I tried adding above snippet in form.phtml and it do not seem to be working.

Comment: Bad approach. Avoid creating blocks in PHP if you can. Main reason: your blocks could be updated from other layout updates and Layout engine will handle errors.

Comment: I used your code its working but i enabled the cache its not working. plz guide me

Comment: perfect answer! +1 @RakeshJesadiyaBhai :)

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, Not working in 2.3.5