# Recently Viewed Products Block

Tags: recently-viewed

Looking for some help with the recently viewed products block/widget in Magento2.3.2.
Have tried three different approaches - creating the widget in the widget section, creating the widget as a new block, and using an existing (functioning) product list block (best sellers) as a template - yet each time the block just appears as this on the frontend:

[image]

This is the code in editor for reference:

{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" uiComponent="widget_recently_viewed" page_size="5" show_attributes="name,image,price" show_buttons="add_to_cart" template="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml"}}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Just keep below code in your template file for get recently viewed products in any place,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

reference  [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199889/magento-2-2-0-display-recently-viewed-products-block-on-product-detail-page).

Comment: Thanks Ranjeet. Doesn't appeared to have fixed the issue though.